# Why is array_search failing

Tags: php

```
$arr =array('username','admin');
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v)
    if(array_search($k, $arr))
        $results[$k] = $v;

print_r($results); // prints nothing and I get a
//$results is undefined error
```

$_GET contains:

```
(
     [r] => p/p
     [i] => 9
     [_s] => true
     [r] => 10
     [p] => 1
     [s] => username
     [o] => asc
     [username] => bd
)
```

so I would expect my $results array to contain 'bd' but instead it is undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array_search` returns the *key*. For `username` that key is `0`, which evaluates to `false`. You need to check for `if (array_search($k, $arr) !== false)`. You should also initialize `$results` before the loop, in case none of the keys are present, otherwise `$results` is never defined.

A much shorter way to do the same thing would be:

```
$results = array_intersect_key($_GET, array_flip(array('username','admin')));
```

Comment: why is the key 0? isn't the key 'username?' oh the key of thearray it's searching nvm. okay thx

Answer (score 1):

The one liner in deceze answer is a pretty cool solution, but in general for this sort of application you'll want to use `in_array()`, not `array_search()`.  Think array_search if you want to know where to find it, in_array if you just want to know it's there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definition of `$results` in your code.

I think what you want is this

```
$arr =array('username','admin');
$results = array();
foreach($_GET as $k=>$v){
    $key = array_search($k, $arr);
    if($key)
        $results[$k] = $v;
}

print_r($results);
```